# undefined is returned from function

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, binary-search

i am working on binary search, and this is first thing i came up with:

```
 function letsGoBinary(firstArray,array,search){
    const middle = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
    if(search === array[middle]) {
       const rv = firstArray.indexOf(array[middle]);
       return rv
    }else if(search < array[middle]){
       var lowerArray = []
       for(var i = 0; i < middle; i++){
           lowerArray.push(array[i])
       }
       letsGoBinary(firstArray,lowerArray, search)
    }else if(search > array[middle]){
       var forwardArray = []
       for(var i = middle + 1; i < array.length; i++){
           forwardArray.push(array[i]);
       }
       letsGoBinary(firstArray,forwardArray,search)
    }else {
       return -1
    } 
 }

console.log(letsGoBinary([1,4,7,14,16],[1,4,7,14,16], 4))
```

and this works if I add `console.log()` in first if statement (`search === array[middle]`) and log the `rv` it logs exact value, and same happens if I log `not found` in else statement, it logs but while logging `letsGoBinary` its value is undefined. how can i fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

beside your question please check how slice method works, loop is not nesessery to get a part of array

also this code is bit meaningless, if you use

```
const rv = firstArray.indexOf(array[middle])
```

then why just in the very beginning not to use

```
const rv = firstArray.indexOf(search)
```

this line of code makes meaningless all your binary search as searches elements one by one

There are very simple solution for it

```
function letsGoBinary(array, search){
    let start = 0
    let end = array.length - 1

    while (start <= end) {
      const middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2)   
      if(search === array[middle]) {
         return middle
      } else if (search < array[middle]) {
         end = middle - 1   
      } else {
         start = middle + 1
      }
    }

   return -1
 }
```

Comment: I am aware all things you said but, i really wanted to build everything from scratch and hence my for loop and slice, both works linearly it does not matter which one i use, i did this for practise. rv variable was just for better visualisation, and yes I was trying to figure out how could i return the index of found element, but ... , is there any other option?

Comment: @iLiA Yes, i edited my answer, if you want to do it  yourself - dont look, i dont know how to hide it in spoiler tag =) Instead if cutting array you just make two variables of beginnig index and last index of search and operate with them

Comment: To sad i did not came up with this, but everyone starts at some point. great answer by the way,

Comment: @iLiA, you cant imagine what kind of code i wrote when i started 17 years ago my programming career, just enjoy coding, no need to do it good...step by step you will get the knack

Answer (score 2):

In the cases where you make a recursive call, you need to return the result.

```
return letsGoBinary(firstArray,lowerArray, search);
```

Comment: why? I am using if else statements and, only one of them will execute, what is point in stopping execution of code if it will automatically

Comment: `return` does more than stopping execution.  It also sets the return value for the function.  If you don't use it, the function will not return any value, which is signaled by the `undefined` response.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with recursive function, you should have the basic cases and then when you want to like perfom a recursive call you are not only calling the function again but you should return the function as response.
For instance if the search number is present into the lowerArray is means that you should return letsGoBinary(firstArray,lowerArray, search) as answer.

I updated your code so that is it:
**Note: Look at the line 11 and 17**

```js
function letsGoBinary(firstArray,array,search){
            const middle = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
            if(search === array[middle]) {
                const rv = firstArray.indexOf(array[middle]);
                return rv
            }else if(search < array[middle]){
                var lowerArray = []
                for(var i = 0; i < middle; i++){
                    lowerArray.push(array[i])
                }
                return letsGoBinary(firstArray,lowerArray, search)
            }else if(search > array[middle]){
                var forwardArray = []
                for(var i = middle + 1; i < array.length; i++){
                    forwardArray.push(array[i]);
                }
                return letsGoBinary(firstArray,forwardArray,search)
            }else {
                return -1
            }
        }

        console.log(letsGoBinary([1,4,7,14,16],[1,4,7,14,16], 4))
```

Comment: A slight correction to "but you should return the function as response".  This should read, "but you should return the result of the function call as response."  In Javascript, simply returning functions is common, but is meant for something else.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because after the first execution when search === array[middle], it is completely returning from letsGoBinary function, hence you have to add another return statement, please find below code snippet:

```
function letsGoBinary(firstArray,array,search){
const middle = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
if(search === array[middle]) {
   const rv = firstArray.indexOf(array[middle]);
   return rv
}else if(search < array[middle]){
   var lowerArray = []
   for(var i = 0; i < middle; i++){
       lowerArray.push(array[i])
   }
   return letsGoBinary(firstArray,lowerArray, search)
}else if(search > array[middle]){
   var forwardArray = []
   for(var i = middle + 1; i < array.length; i++){
       forwardArray.push(array[i]);
       }
       return letsGoBinary(firstArray,forwardArray,search)
    }else {
       return -1
    } 
 }

console.log(letsGoBinary([1,4,7,14,16],[1,4,7,14,16], 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Dmitry Reutov is great.  If you'd prefer a recursive version, this is a similar approach, but using recursion rather than a `while` loop:

```js
const letsGoBinary = (
  sortedArray, 
  value, 
  start = 0, 
  end = sortedArray .length - 1, 
  middle = Math.floor ((end + start) / 2)
) =>
  start > end
    ? -1
  : sortedArray [middle] == value
    ? middle
  : sortedArray [middle] < value
    ? letsGoBinary (sortedArray, value, middle + 1, end)
  : letsGoBinary (sortedArray, value, start, middle - 1)

console .log (
  letsGoBinary ([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233], 34)
)
```

Both these solutions use only a single array, relying on `start`, `end`, and `middle` indices to track the current search position.

This version defaults `start` and `end` on the first call, and then passes them on subsequent searches.  `middle` is calculated on each call as the closest integer midpoint between `start` and `end`.

For this example, the first call uses `start` and `end` of `0` and `12` making `middle` `6`, and the value we're testing would be `sortedArray[6]`, which is `13`.  This is less than the search value of `34`, so we call again with `7` and `12`, which makes `middle` into `9` and the test value `55`.  That is larger than `34` so we call with `7` and `8`, `middle` of `7`, test value `21`.  That one is less than our value, and we call one more time with `start` and `end` both `8`, which gives us a `middle` of `8` and a test value of `34`.  Since that equals our value, we return `8`.  If we had missed -- perhaps we were searching for `35` instead -- then we would call again with `start` of `9` and `end` of `8`, and would return `-1`, because `start` > `end`.  Or if we had been searching for `33` instead, we would have `start` of `8` and `end` of `7`, with the same `-1` result.